# How to add an user input to to an URL with Tkinter?

Tags: json, python-3.x, api, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to create a program in which currency conversion is crucial. I have an API URL to which I want to add user input (amount that is supposed to be converted) not to display it in a label but to work with it later on.

```
input = Entry(root)

URL = "https://www.myawesomeurl.com/exchangerate/amout="
payload = {}
headers = {"apikey": "awjdwahduwahdwauduw"}

response = requests.request("GET", URL, headers=headers, data = payload)

status_code = response.status_code
result = response.text
```

I'm new to programming so any help and tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please have a look at the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and in particular to https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to change your code sample so that people can try it out without needing to figure out by themselves which modules they need to import and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a submit function to process your data. Ex.

```py
import tkinter
import requests

root = tkinter.Tk()


def submitamount():
    amounttext = amount.get()
    URL = f"https://www.myawesomeurl.com/exchangerate/amout={amounttext}"
    payload = {}
    headers = {"apikey": "awjdwahduwahdwauduw"}

    response = requests.request("GET", URL, headers=headers, data=payload)

    status_code = response.status_code
    result = response.text

    # Do stuff here / call another function to do stuff
    #
    # If you want to make some variables accessible to other parts of 
    # the code, simply define them before this function is declared; 
    # Ex.
    #
    # Instead of:
    #   root = tkinter.Tk()
    #   ...
    #   def submitamount():
    #        ...
    #
    # Do:
    #   root = tkinter.Tk()
    #   ...
    #   response = None
    #   status_code = None
    #   result = None
    #
    #   def submitamount():
    #        ...
    #


amount = tkinter.Entry(root)
amount.pack()

submit = tkinter.Button(text="Submit", command=submitamount)
submit.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

If you need a more thorough explanation, please let me know!

Comment: You could change the URL reassignment line to `URL = URL + amounttext`. Of course, this won't work if the amount part is not at the end, but just another way to do it.